# Is this normal or due to bug in mongodb?

Tags: linux, mongodb, schema, nosql

I am new to mongodb and i installed it on xen para virtual vm and when given command

"**mongo**" terminal freezed and on the top output command mongo is taking almost 100% CPU.

Is this a bug,or does the **mongo** command made the scheduler to consider the process **interactive** and  resulted in more cpu usage?

**Running Mongo 2.0.4,Ubuntu 12.04, 3.2.0-23-generic** as VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal behavior, no, the mongo shell itself is quite lightweight and should consume very little resources unless you are running something complex in terms of javascript.  A simple connection to a `mongod` instance should not cause this kind of problem.  Despite running the shell and `mongod` on multiple VMs I have never seen this behavior, hence I can't really suggest what might be causing it.

As a general recommendation, I would not use 2.0.4, it is [well over a year](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/aQ20-cvuC3c) old, and has been superseded by 5 minor versions in the 2.0 branch (as of writing this) and by 2 major versions (2.2 and 2.4).  Hence, you might be running into an old bug that I am not remembering.  At the very least I would recommend getting hold of 2.0.9 and preferably using 2.4.4+